# Which object is seen if light reflects from one object after another?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

This is a question I ask because I am having trouble understanding how mirrors work and how angle of object placed, your eye placed and how angle of light reflected all affect how object is seen. So my question basically is that imagine there are multiple objects like a book, a wall,and finally a pair of human eyes. Lets says light first striked a upright book, where some rays are reflected and the reflected rays then hit the wall as it is traveling. Then imagine the some of the reflected light that hit the wall is again reflected to some direction where your eyes are now positioned. Now the question is that which object is seen by you? The wall or the book? I think you see the wall but now if instead of wall we have a mirror. Do you see the book or the mirror? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered doing an experiment to find out? If you look at a wall, do you see the wall or do you see reflections of other things?

Answer (score 1):

Books and walls scatter light in every direction but mirrors reflect light in a straight line. You see objects which scatter light and you see reflections in objects which reflect light.

Comment: *Diffuse* reflection describes reflection off of walls and books whereas mirrors produce *regular* or *specular* reflection.